# How to set my form active from global hotkey?

Tags: c#, window

I have form named Form1. I set Hotkey Ctrl + G do:

```
Show();
Active();
TopMost = true;
TopMost = false;
TextBox1.Focus();
```

While I'm typing in Notepad, I press that hotkey, my Form1 appeared, like this:
[image]

Both Notepad and Form1 have text cursor, but when continue typing, Form1.TextBox1 doesnt get input, but Notepad get.

But when open solution by Visual Studio and Debugging (F5), my Form1 get input, and Notepad doesnt.

Can you help me solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Setting the form's TopMost property is not a solution, as you found out.  Diagnosing the problem with your WM_HOTKEY code from the screenshot isn't possible, you need to post code.

Comment: I set this action for a global hook. I tried Eric J.'s solution (at below) but i see that it only work if I set it for a button (or other control), but dont work for global hook

Comment: Well, there you go, don't use a global hook.  Type "registerhotkey" in the Search box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling ShowWindowAsync and SetForegroundWindow from your WinForms process on itself as outlined here:

http://weimenglee.blogspot.com/2007/01/programmatically-switch-to-another.html

It seems that notepad is still the active application.

Comment: I did what you say, but perhap there is a issue: when I press hotkey, the Notepad icon still active, but my Form1 icon at Taskbar become flash

Comment: The problem might be this:
 
(from the SetForegroundWindow() documentation)
Windows NT 5.0 and later: An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user is working with another window. Instead, SetForegroundWindow will activate the window (see SetActiveWindow) and call the FlashWindowEx function to notify the user.

Comment: Hmmm... I know for a fact that it is *possible* to force a window to have the focus.  For example, Visual Studio does that while debugging (I'll sometimes be typing in a program I'm debugging and VS will switch to the foreground due to hitting an unexpected Exception.